# How to safe guard against broken jenkinsfiles causing pipelines to run indefinitely?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have my repo getting polled every 5 mins.

But I found that if the jenkinsfile is totally broken the pipeline will fail with "This stage has no steps".

Then every 5 mins it will retry it and keep failing.

How do I safe guard against this? Can I set a threshold somewhere so if this happens it doesn't churn forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using scm polling, it should only build if there are changes. Sounds like you may be building on a cron schedule. Here is the different syntax for each in a declarative pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    triggers {
        cron('H/4 * * * 1-5')
        pollSCM('0 0 * * 0')
    }
}
```

Or you could do is trigger the builds from a webhook instead of starting a new build every 5 minutes.

If you really just want to throttle the builds so you can't do more than *n* builds in *x* time, you can set this property:

```
properties([[$class: 'JobPropertyImpl', throttle: [count: 1, durationName: 'hour']])
```