# Git LFS pull after checkout results in no step in jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

## Problem

After enable `Git LFS pull after checkout`, jenkins pipeline says "This stage has no steps".

I tried to enable it from either jenkins multibranch configuration or Jenkinsfile (which I name it Jenkinsfile_ios since I have another one for android) but both of their results are the same.

I've done lots of googling but there's no issue relate to this. I am wondering if somebody already encountered this or it is a bug from git plugin.
Right now I am signing up to file issue to Jenkins. After being approved I will file the issue. But before then hopefully somebody can help with this strange issue.

Thanks!

## Environment

osx high sierra
Jenkins 2.89.2

#### Jenkins Plugins (filtered, not through list)

git 3.7.0 (same issue in 3.6.4)
git-client 2.7.0
git-server 1.7
pipeline-build-step 2.6
pipeline-github-lib 1.0
pipeline-graph-analysis 1.6
pipeline-input-step 2.8
pipeline-milestone-step 1.3.1
pipeline-model-api  1.2.5
pipeline-model-declarative-agent    1.1.1
pipeline-model-definition   1.2.5
pipeline-model-extensions   1.2.5
pipeline-rest-api   2.9
pipeline-stage-step 2.3
pipeline-stage-tags-metadata    1.2.5
pipeline-stage-view 2.9

Comment: Is it because there is no changes detected? (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46336113/6309)

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with polling since I run the pipeline manually. It shows up something similar to this. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/attachment/38668/no-console-in-blue-ocean.png

Answer (score 0):

"This stage has no steps" is shown when the pipeline didn't get executed at all. This means that the branch on which the Jenkinsfile is present didn't get checkout.

This can be due to some other files present aswell. Enable GitLFS option in jenkins job configuration.

Comment: As @JackSparow pointed, this is a generic error. It is probably being caused by lack of authentication in git lfs step.